# Ruby-on-Rails - Conditional database condition depending on action

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I am no master, but I have been using `Ruby-On-Rails` for quite few years now and consider myself well-versed in it. Additionally, I have been working as web developer for last 10 years, starting with `.Net`.

I `.Net` we used to manually create database connection before firing any query or making a transaction. But `Rails` on the other hand, while spawning a new thread for request, fires a bag of initialization process which includes setting up a database connection.

Now we are working on a project, where we may not have a need for DB connection for every action. Is it somehow possible to override the default DB connection function and do it action-wise (a `before_filter` maybe)?

PS: Another way I thought of creating an additional `Sinatra` web application, which houses all such actions and use them instead to do the work or get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm where did you read Rails sets up a database connection for every request? My understanding is a connection is checked out from the connection pool when needed.

Also I'm surprised this is a big issue! If you don't need to hit the database (which implies no authentication, right?) then you should be caching the entire response, server-side and client-side.

Check out the guide on caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html and Dalli https://github.com/mperham/dalli

Separating the client app from the data layer (so Rails on top of an API) is a nice architecture I've used for a project with success. I'd suggest Grape instead of Sinatra however.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that statement. You are right. Just like in .Net, it basically pools the connections and pick one when needed. I know about caching but seems not logical in current scope as the actions will actually just do some calculations (mostly AJAX based) and return result.